Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported
I have a method where I changed the endswith logic with a conditional base as follows from then it starts throwing the exception
public async Task<IEnumerable<CorpTransaction_DTO>> GetTransactionDetailByCorpNumber(string corpNumber)
{
    var query = from rm in _gpModel.RM20101
                join cm in _gpModel.RM00101.AsNoTracking() on rm.CUSTNMBR equals cm.CUSTNMBR
                join rm1 in _gpModel.RM20201 on rm.DOCNUMBR equals rm1.APTODCNM into rm1Join
                from rm1 in rm1Join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join so in _gpModel.SOP30200.AsNoTracking() on rm.DOCNUMBR equals so.SOPNUMBE into soJoin
                from sop in soJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join sy in _gpModel.SY03900.AsNoTracking() on sop.NOTEINDX equals sy.NOTEINDX into syJoin
                from sy in syJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                **where
                new string(rm.SLPRSNID.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) == corpNumber ||
                (
                    rm.SLPRSNID.EndsWith(corpNumber) &&
                    !ApplicationConstants.ExcludedPrefixes.Any(prefix => rm.SLPRSNID.StartsWith(prefix))
                )**
                orderby rm.DOCDATE descending
                select new CorpTransaction_DTO
                {
                    DOCDATE = rm.DOCDATE,
                    RMDTYPAL = rm.RMDTYPAL,
                    AgentId = cm.CUSTNMBR.Trim(),
                    AgentName = cm.CUSTNAME.Trim(),
                    Batch = rm.BACHNUMB.Trim(),
                    InvoiceNumber = rm.DOCNUMBR.Trim(),
                    DUEDATE = rm.DUEDATE,
                    InvoiceType = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_CASH_RECEIPT ? ApplicationConstants.INVOICETYPE_PAYMENT :
                                  rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE ? ApplicationConstants.INVOICETYPE_INVOICE :
                                  rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_DEBIT_MEMO || rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_CREDIT_MEMO
                                  || rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_Return ? ApplicationConstants.INVOICETYPE_ADJ : string.Empty,
                    InvoiceStatus = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE ? (rm.CURTRXAM == 0 ?
                    ApplicationConstants.INVOICESTATUS_PAID : rm.CURTRXAM < rm.ORTRXAMT ? ApplicationConstants.INVOICESTATUS_PARTIALLY_PAID : ApplicationConstants.INVOICESTATUS_UNPAID)
                    : null,
                    Amount = rm.ORTRXAMT,
                    Balance = rm.CURTRXAM,
                    SubType = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_CASH_RECEIPT || rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_DEBIT_MEMO ? string.Empty :
                    rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_CREDIT_MEMO ? ApplicationConstants.INV_SUB_TYPE_DISCOUNT : rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_Return ? ApplicationConstants.INV_SUB_TYPE_RETRUN : string.Empty,
                    InvoiceDescription = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE && sy != null ? sy.TXTFIELD ?? string.Empty : string.Empty,
                    RequestedBy = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE && sy != null ? sy.TXTFIELD ?? string.Empty : string.Empty,
                    SourceSystem = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE && sy != null ? sy.TXTFIELD ?? string.Empty : string.Empty,
                    FormattedInvoiceNumber = rm.RMDTYPAL == ApplicationConstants.RMDTYPAL_SALES_INVOICE ? rm.SLPRSNID.Trim() + " - " + rm.DOCNUMBR.Trim() : string.Empty
                };

    // Execute the query and get the list of DTOs
    var corpDto = await query.ToListAsync();

    // Apply transformations to the list of DTOs
    corpDto.ForEach(account => account.SubType = account.RMDTYPAL == 1 ? GPHelper.SplitStringToColumns(account.InvoiceDescription).InvoiceDescription : account.SubType);
    corpDto.ForEach(account => account.InvoiceDescription = GPHelper.SplitStringToColumns(account.InvoiceDescription).InvoiceDescription);
    corpDto.ForEach(account => account.RequestedBy = GPHelper.SplitStringToColumns(account.RequestedBy).RequestedBy);
    corpDto.ForEach(account => account.SourceSystem = GPHelper.SplitStringToColumns(account.SourceSystem).SourceSystem);

    // Group by DOCNUMBR and select the first entry from each group
    corpDto = corpDto.GroupBy(account => account.DOCNUMBR).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();

    return corpDto;
}

If I remove this condition it works good
where new string(rm.SLPRSNID.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) == corpNumber ||
(
rm.SLPRSNID.EndsWith(corpNumber) &&
!ApplicationConstants.ExcludedPrefixes.Any(prefix => rm.SLPRSNID.StartsWith(prefix))
)

Here is my model for the same
public class CorpTransaction_DTO
{
    public DateTime DOCDATE { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string DOCNUMBR { get; set; }
    public DateTime DUEDATE { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceStatus { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPayment { get; set; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }
    public string PaymentDescription { get; set; }
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceDescription { get; set; }
    public string FormattedInvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
    public int RMDTYPAL { get; set; }
}

I have my sql as follows for the base table as follows
DECLARE @inputNumber VARCHAR(20) = '23658';  -- Change this input value as needed

SELECT SLPRSNID, *
FROM RM20101
WHERE 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(SLPRSNID, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SLPRSNID), LEN(SLPRSNID)) AS VARCHAR(20)) = @inputNumber  -- Matches if the numeric portion equals the input
    OR (
        RIGHT(SLPRSNID, LEN(@inputNumber)) = @inputNumber AND
        LEFT(SLPRSNID, LEN(SLPRSNID) - LEN(@inputNumber))
        NOT IN ('C-', 'F-', 'LLC-', 'LP-', 'NFP-', 'P-', 'PF-', 'RB-', 'RT-')  -- Excludes specified prefixes
    );


Entity Framework has to parse the C# you've written in your query, and apply rules and logic to turn it into SQL. It doesn't recognise the pattern new string(rm.SLPRSNID.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) == corpNumber, and it doesn't know how to turn it into SQL

K how can I correct it

First work out what you would write in SQL, then look up whether there's a translation for that function, e.g. in these docs (for SQL server). For example, it looks like you're trying to test whether a string is numeric? The SQL Server function would be ISNUMERIC, and the translation is EF.Functions.IsNumeric

@Developer to correct this, stop trying to write SQL in C#. You're using EF, an Object-to-Relational Mapper. It deals with entities, not tables. You don't need any explicit JOINs in C#, the ORM itself will generate the necessary JOINS based on the relations between the entities.

You cannot call the string constructor to create a string from an array inside a linq query, as it has no sql translation. To achieve the same logic, you could consider storing the numeric part of the column in a separate column to compare that column directly with the corpnumber variable. This will also give you much better performance.

Can I get the corrected version I tried many but couldn't

This is untested, but it looks like you just need padindex, and it is in EF functions
EF.Functions.PatIndex

But I think the alternative where you just execute the sql with Ef core will be better for your codebase.

The exception you're encountering may be due to how LINQ to Entities translates your query, especially with the string operations like EndsWith, StartsWith, and the construction of new string(...). Entity Framework may not support some of these operations directly in the query.
Break the query into two parts: Execute the filtering with Where in memory after fetching a larger result set.
Refactor the logic: Consider using .ToList() on the relevant data set before applying the string filters. For example:
                     // Add your joins here
                     select rm).ToListAsync();

var filteredResults = results.Where(rm =>
    new string(rm.SLPRSNID.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()) == corpNumber ||
    (rm.SLPRSNID.EndsWith(corpNumber) &&
    !ApplicationConstants.ExcludedPrefixes.Any(prefix => rm.SLPRSNID.StartsWith(prefix)))
).Select(rm => new CorpTransaction_DTO
{
    // Your mapping here
}).ToLis();```

This approach pulls the data into memory before applying the string filters, which avoids issues with unsupported operations in the LINQ query.


Can I get the complete piece of code
